# VB.net get XML attribute id if you know its one of the child values

Tags: xml, vb.net, listbox

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patient_Data>
  <Patient ID="1">
    <Patient_Name>john</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>1234</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>12</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>11</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>18-03-15</Admit_date>
    <Admit_time>02:24:17</Admit_time>
    <Discharge_date></Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="2">
    <Patient_Name>rambo</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>123456</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>8</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>6</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>18-03-15</Admit_date>
    <Admit_time>02:24:33</Admit_time>
    <Discharge_date></Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="3">
    <Patient_Name>arnold</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>12345678</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>88</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>99</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>18-03-15</Admit_date>
    <Admit_time>02:24:47</Admit_time>
    <Discharge_date>30/5/14</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="4">
    <Patient_Name>john</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>12345678</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>88</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>99</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>18-03-15</Admit_date>
    <Admit_time>02:25:33</Admit_time>
    <Discharge_date>2/3/14</Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
  <Patient ID="5">
    <Patient_Name>big show</Patient_Name>
    <BPL_card_no.>12345</BPL_card_no.>
    <Room_no.>66</Room_no.>
    <Bed_no.>7</Bed_no.>
    <Admit_date>18-03-15</Admit_date>
    <Admit_time>02:31:38</Admit_time>
    <Discharge_date></Discharge_date>
  </Patient>
</Patient_Data>
```

Now i have a `textbox`, with search `button`, a `listbox`.
When the user types a name and clicks the search button, following query runs:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\database.xml")
For Each itm In doc.Descendants("Patient_Name")
            If itm = TextBox1.Text Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itm.Value)
            End If
Next
```

This adds all names typed to the `listbox`. After this on `listbox` `selectedindexchanged` event i have the following query:

```
    Dim patientData = From el In doc.Element("Patient_Data").Elements("Patient")
Where el.Element("Patient_Name") = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Select New With {.Name = el.Element("Patient_Name").Value, _
    .Bpl = el.Element("BPL_card_no.").Value, _
    .Room = el.Element("Room_no.").Value, _
    .Bed = el.Element("Bed_no.").Value, _
    .AdmitDt = el.Element("Admit_date").Value, _
    .DischargeDt = el.Element("Discharge_date").Value}
        For Each el In patientData
            TextBox2.Text = el.Name
            TextBox3.Text = el.Bpl
            TextBox4.Text = el.Room
            TextBox5.Text = el.Bed
            TextBox8.Text = el.AdmitDt
            TextBox6.Text = el.DischargeDt
        Next
```

This displays the respected name related data into respective textboxes.
The problem is that when the user searches for "john", the listbox has two items but selecting any of the listbox items displays only data of person with first name. Help
Thanks. I think i can use the ids but i couldnt get the query to get ids of the names searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign datatable as datasource to the listbox and set its DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.I think the following code should help.

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\database.xml")
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Name")
dt.Columns.Add("ID")
For Each itm In doc.Descendants("Patient_Name")
    If itm = "john" Then
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        dr("Name") = itm.Value
        dr("ID") = itm.Parent.FirstAttribute
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    End If
Next
ListBox1.DataSource = dt
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

In the listbox selectedindexchanged event write the following query:

```
     Dim patientData = From el In doc.Element("Patient_Data").Elements("Patient") _
        Where (el.Element("Patient_Name") = ListBox1.Text.ToString) _
     Select New With {.Name = el.Element("Patient_Name").Value, _
   .Bpl = el.Element("BPL_card_no.").Value, _
   .Room = el.Element("Room_no.").Value, _
   .Bed = el.Element("Bed_no.").Value, _
   .AdmitDt = el.Element("Admit_date").Value, _
   .DischargeDt = el.Element("Discharge_date").Value, _
   .ParentID = el.Element("Admit_date").Parent.FirstAttribute}
        For Each el In patientData
            If el.ParentID.ToString = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString Then
               TextBox2.Text = el.Name
               TextBox3.Text = el.Bpl
               TextBox4.Text = el.Room
               TextBox5.Text = el.Bed
               TextBox8.Text = el.AdmitDt
               TextBox6.Text = el.DischargeDt
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there away of loading the xml to datasource. I think i'll have to convert the xml to datasource, or connect via dataset, or change my default database ie. xml to sql. Which one is easy ? Any suggestions. Or is there any other, simpler way as i earlier said of using IDs.

Comment: check and use the code in my answer, i think it will work for you

Comment: Oh yes that did it !. Got it thats how i should have used the attribute property. Didnt know, anyway Thanks. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the XML into dataset and then query on the dataset instead of querying XML

```
            Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\database.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)

            ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Patient_Name"
            ListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

In the listbox selectedindexchanged event write the following query:

```
            Dim drArr As DataRow() = CType(ListBox1.DataSource, DataTable).Select("ID = " & CInt(ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString))
            If Not drArr Is Nothing AndAlso drArr.Length > 0 Then
                TextBox2.Text = drArr(0)("Patient_Name")
                TextBox3.Text = drArr(0)("BPL_card_no.")
                TextBox4.Text = drArr(0)("Room_no.")
                TextBox5.Text = drArr(0)("Bed_no.")
                TextBox8.Text = drArr(0)("Admit_date")
                TextBox6.Text = drArr(0)("Discharge_date")
            End If
```

Comment: One thing I want to ask, Pankti, if I want to search by `Admit_date` or `Discharge_date` and still obtain the respected name in listbox I tried and changed `itm.value` to `itm.Parent.Element("Patient_Name").value` the query works fine with `Admit_date` but when using with `Discharge_date` nothing gets displayed.

Comment: It works for me for Discharge_date also so can you show me your code and requirement so that i can check